# Android: Linespacing between 1st and 2nd line on multiline text wrong

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` that displays 13 labels by using '\n'. I chose to use only one View, since android-layouting tends to get very slow if you have more than a couple of `TextView`s.

I set line-spacing-multiplier to 1.3x and have the problem that between the first and the second line there's about 5 to 10 px more space than between the others. There are no special characters like Ö in the labels, everyone of them consists of capital letters only.

Is this a known bug?

Comment: "android-layouting tends to get very slow if you have more than a couple of TextViews" ? In my current project I made an activity with a custom number of buttons , and I happen to display ~25 buttons with no problem (I guess buttons are heavier than textviews) I'm using a galaxy mini with android 2.3.6 it's a very old model, and a small one as well so I guess it's a weak phone but can handle some views

Comment: Possible that old version has still some speed. My experiences are with Android 3.0 - 4.2. I don't know if Buttons are heavier, profiling would show that.